# Can we change the middle number of the Document ID which is generated by the Document ID feature

Tags: document-id

I need to change the middle number of a auto generated document ID to a shorter number. Can you let me know if this is possible. 
Please find below the marked number in red which needs to be changed.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Document ID has the format `PREFIX-LISTID-ITEMID`

The Prefix text is the only one that is configurable.

You can change that from the Document ID Settings page.